# Capture a SkeneKit scene as video

Tags: ios, scenekit, metal

I'm using SceneKit with Metal (not openGL) & would like to allow a user to record a video of him playing the game. Any ideas how can I render the scene to a video? (There's no need to record the scene audio, which might make it more simple)

Comment: How about capture `SKView` to `UIImage` every n frames and make video?

Comment: SKView is SpriteKit class, while I'm talking about SceneKit. Yet, I can capture SCNView to image every n frames and make a video. But I'm looking for more elegant solution.

Comment: Would ReplayKit not work for this?

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd add it as an answer:

ReplayKit should do the job fine, though it does require iOS9 and a device that supports Metal (A7 or later). I've never used it but from what I remember of WWDC 2015 it only required a few lines of code to set up. There's tons of tutorials on it available on the net.

[This one](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-9-an-introduction-to-replaykit--cms-25458) seems to include most bits such as starting and stopping recording, as well as excluding interface objects from the video if required.

Comment: Yes, ReplayKit is great. I didn't know about this framework. If Apple only give you the video output instead of forcing you to use their own UI preview to save/share the video, it would be wonderful.